# Find image urls that throw "Not Found" error in browser given bad name format but they actually exist

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I have thousands of image urls stored in a table, one per row. The thing is that some of them have bad formatted names with spaces, accented characters, etc, ie like this:

```
https://www.greatsite.com/upload/memdocs/111046-carte d'identit� 001-072716141540.jpg
```

When opening this url in a browser, the following error is output:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /upload/memdocs/111046-carte d'identitï¿½ 001-072716141540.jpg was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I need to programatically find all the image urls that throw this "Not Found" error (in order to later correctly format the image url name).

So far I am trying to use getimagesize() and file_get_contents() but no luck. getimagesize() not always work because I think it kind of fixes the image name, because for example for the url above, it actually does returns and array with the image info. And file_get_contents() always returns something regardless of wether the image url throws the "Not Found" error or not.

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this? I hope I made sense. Thanks

Comment: ther are many bot scripts for validationg links on your own site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the images from DB and iterate over them with foreach. In the foreach try checking if file exist. Example:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $valid = is_file($imageDir.$image->path);
}
```

is_file is optimal way to check if file exist. file_get_contents will read the whole file which is slow.

Or you can just do regex on the image path:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $valid = preg_match('/[0-9a-zA-Z\$-_\.\+!\*'\(\),];\/\?\:\@=\&/', $image->path);
}
```

I`m not 100% sure if this regex would properly validate all the urls .... but most of them.

Comment: I just tried and unfortunately still not working: `is_file( /home/greatsite/public_html/upload/memdocs/111046-carte d'identit� 001-072716141540.jpg )` returns `true` even though that url shows the "Not Found" error in the browser. I need to know if the url shows the "Not Found" error when displayed in the browser. Any other thought? Please

Comment: Can you add image url here?

Answer (score 0):

You should get headers doing web request:

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
 $url = 'https://www.greatsite.com/'.$image;
 $file_headers = @get_headers($url);
 if($file_headers && $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
  // URL Not Found do something to log it
 }
}
```

There are many other ways, using CURL, etc, but I find this easiest